Check Engine light on with “Emissions System Problem” Alert
Just went to autozone to get a diagnostic on my check engine light that just came on. The results were that my Fuel cap is loose, but I have a 2022 Honda Civic sport, which has a capless fuel cap. My cars warning alert says “Emissions system problem. Power may be reduced”. I called my Honda dealership And they asked me to bring it in for a diagnostic there, but I am currently four hours away.
Think I will be ok to drive 230+ miles with this light and message? Any suggestions?

Of course there is a fuel cap, and it's built into the flap.
